# Disable suggestion/syntax highlighting in both Intellij Idea and Android studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, highlight

I wish to disable highlighting such as

- "change var to val"
- "can be inlined"

and the likes. How do I do that?
(I don't want to disable error highlighting)

I tried disabling some "inspection" in the settings, but it didn't do what I wanted.

Comment: I really don't recommend using var instead of val without a strong need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Alt+Enter on the warning
2. More actions
3. Disable inspection, or "Suppress for file"

[image]